# user input using while loop to store data

Tags: java

Can you please tell me what is wrong with the following java code.

I am trying to collect input from the user through `Scanner` class object then store it in an `array` by using while but it would be infinite loop if i don't supply a `break` condition , so i thought to `break` when the input equals *"q"*, but it didn't work.

```
import java.util.*;
public class ProjectOne{
    public static void main (String []arg){
        ArrayList  one = new ArrayList();
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter");
        String x = input.next();       
        while ( input.hasNext()){
           if (x !="q"){
              one.add(input);
           }
           if (x == "q")
           {
              break;
           }
           System.out.println(one);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: *what is wrong with the following java code*: it's unreadable because there are 4 empty lines between each line, and the code is not indented. Don't post the question until it looks perfect in the preview.

Comment: See my update answer. I think that is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't compare `String` with `==`. Use `.equals()` like

```
if (!x.equals("q")){
```

and

```
if (x.equals("q"))
```

**Note** : I think that  you aren't using `Scanner` correctly. You take the input, but keep checking `x`, instead of the input.

Answer (score 0):

Do not compare strings like `x =="q"`
USE **.equals** function in java for string comparison. 
Replace your code with: `x.equals("q") for x =="q"` and `!x.equals("q") for x !="q"`

Answer (score 0):

You are not reading updated value from `Scanner`. Below is updated code for your reference after correcting formatting and other errors. Also, instead of `==` sign, use `equals()` method for string comparison -

```
import java.util.*;

public class ProjectOne{ 

public static void main (String []arg ){

    ArrayList one = new ArrayList();
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter");
    String x = null;
    while ( input.hasNext()) {
      x = input.next();
      if (!x.equals("q")) {
          one.add(x);
      }
      if (x.equals("q")){
          break;
      }
  }
      System.out.println(one);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Scanner reads everything before your ENTER - the whole line you input.

I think that is what you need:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ProjectOne

{ public static void main (String []arg ){
    ArrayList  one = new ArrayList();
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter");
    String pattern;
    String x = input.next();
    while (true){
        String line = input.next();
        if(line.contains("q"))break;
        else{
            x = x + " " + line;
            }
    }
    System.out.println(x);
}
```